# Entity Framework - Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I need to select Entity Objects based on the name of page controls.

There are two scenarios where I need to access Entities based on a string (I am dynamically selecting these based on the names of user controls placed on a page:

Example 1) - 
Here I would like to somehow change db.PersonalDetails to a string substitution where the db.PersonalDetails is a variable.

```
EntityObject obj = null;
obj = (from q in db.PersonalDetails where q.AppFormId==FormApplicationId select q).SingleOrDefault();
```

Example 2)
Here I would like to dynamically set the return type, in this case it is PersonalDetail but I would like to be able to set this dynamically. I can use reflection to get the type but I am unable to then say " as obj.GetType() " as it errors.

```
EntityObject obj = null;
obj = returnUpdatedObj(obj) as PersonalDetail;
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am desperate to find a solution to this so if any more information is required to explain the issue please let me know.

Comment: This is way too abstract to even start to say anything sensible. Show the code where you need assistance.

Comment: "as obj.GetType()" makes no sense. "as" is (sort of) used to change the static type -- the type the compiler knows about. "obj.GetType()" determines the dynamic type, and the compiler cannot possibly know about that, because there is no obj until you actually run the code, and you don't need to cast to change the dynamic type: it is already what you're trying to make it. I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: What I am trying to do:: I've got an XML file that contains a list of controls that need to appear on a page. Each of the controls is loaded dynamically at runtime as the number and type of controls can be changed dynamically. Each of the control names matches a SQL Server table of the same name, and each control input field name matches a column in the table. So, when a form is submitted, I loop through the controls and select the entity/s that they relate to, then using reflection, I run through the control input fields and update the entity fields.

Comment: I have this working at the moment but I have a growing case select statement that is checking the name of the control and then specifically getting the object. What I would like is to find the type of the Entity by string name (which I can do) and then create or update that type of object.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) you could do something like I do here in [this](http://wimpool.nl/blog/DotNet/extending-entity-framework-4-with-uniquevalidator) blog post. Make an expresion Tree and use that expression tree in

```
context.Set<T>.Where(expression);
```

For 2) it looks like you need generic function:

```
    private static T DoSomething<T>(T obj)
    {
        return obj;
    }
```